# Connection string with ASP.Net

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-config

I have a solution with three projects:

1. A web application (WA)
2. A Data Model Layer (DML) using code first, and
3. A Data Access Layer (DAL)

The WA’s `web.config` and the DML's `app.config` each have a connection string section specifying a connection string for the database.

I've noticed that the DML connection string doesn't really matter. So is it safe to completely remove this section from the `app.config` file?

Also, why is this string unused? Finally, I'm guessing when the application is run, the connection to the database is established using the connection string in the `web.config` file and the database definition is managed by the DML/DAL?

Is this because the other projects aren’t really being run per se, just the methods and properties are being referenced? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can remove connection string from DML's app.config.
It is unused because you are starting the web application and only it's config does matter at runtime.

Answer (score 0):

Everything needs to go into your app.config / web.config. The config files on the library project only help you to keep track of things that need to go into your app.config